# Why do variations of this t.test require different coding? (R)

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

New to R and trying to get my head around it's coding (new to coding in general)

My question is, running t-tests (paired and independent) I have to change the formula for it to recognise my columns. The following both work; however the 'paired' code will not work if styled like the 'independent' code (with data = '').

Independent: `t.test(Nicotine ~ Brand, data = nicotine, alternative='two.sided', conf.level=.95, var.equal=FALSE)`

Paired: `with(omega3, t.test(Before, After, paired = TRUE, alternative='greater', conf.level=.95))`

Why does this happen? ideally I'd prefer to not use the `with` formula, but I cannot understand why it will not recognize  "Before" and "After" when I add the argument `data = omega3`

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thom

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with the way the data are used by the function. When you're using a formula, you're telling R: "Use this variable as my predictor (independent var), and this other one as my outcome (dependent var)". In the case of the independent samples t-test, you'd have:

```
continuous.variable  ~  dichotomous.variable
(outcome/dependent)     (predictor/independent)
```

With paired-samples, you have no such thing as a "predictor" (or more largely speaking "explanatory variable"). You simply have two columns that you wish to compare against one another.

So you can see the *formula notation* as a nice feature of R, but one which you cannot use in every situation.

Besides, **there are alternatives to using `with` function :**

```
t.test(Before, After, paired = TRUE, alternative='greater', conf.level=.95, data=omega3)
# or
t.test(omega3$Before, omega3$After, paired = TRUE, alternative='greater', conf.level=.95)
```